# Connecting frontend flask container to backend flask container

Tags: docker, flask

I'm new to docker and I'm trying to connect 2 flask containers together using docker-compose.yml file:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: "3.7"
    services:
      frontend:
        build:
          context: ./frontEnd
        container_name: frontend
        depends_on: [backend]
        ports: 
          - "5000:1973"
        networks:
          - my_own_network
        links:
          - "backend:backend"
      backend:
        build:
          context: ./backEnd
        container_name: backend
        ports:
          - "5001:5000"
        networks:
          - my_own_network
      networks:
          my_own_network:
```

**backend.py**

```
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, request  
    my_app = Flask(__name__)
    @my_app.route('/generateKeys',methods = ['POST'])
    def generateKeys() :
        values = request.get_json()
        if (values['fullname']=="NAAAME" and values['pass']=="PASS"):
            return 'new_key : HERES_YOUR_KEY' , 201
        else :
            return '_error : Invalid submitted informations' , 300
    if __name__ == '__main__' :
        my_app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

**frontend.py**

```
    from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template , request 
    import requests , json , ast
    BackENDnode = 'http://backend:5000'
    FE_app = Flask(__name__ , template_folder = 'templates')
    @FE_app.route('/SubmitCitizenInfo', methods=['POST'])
    def submit_citizen_informations():
        citizen_object = {
            'fullname' : str(request.form["citizen_name"]),
            'pass' : str(request.form["citizen_pass"]),
        }
        keys_url = "{}/generateKeys".format(BackENDnode)
        keys_request = requests.post( keys_url,
            json = citizen_object,
            headers={'Content-type' : 'application/json'})
        if not keys_request.status_code == 300 || not keys_request.status_code == 201 :
            err = '_error : Something went wrong somehow '+str(keys_url)
            return render_template('/Public/error.html', err = err )
    if __name__ == '__main__' :
        FE_app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', debug=True ,port=1973)
```

**Error.html_displaying**

_error : Something went wrong somehow http://backend:5000/generateKeys

docker-compose --version

> docker-compose version 1.26.0, build d4451659

my directory tree :

> ```
> - docker-compose.yml
> - backEnd
>     |- Dockefile
>     |- backend.py
>     |- BErequirements.txt
> - frontEnd : 
>     |- Dockerfile
>     |- frontend.py
>     |- FErequirements.txt
>     |- templates
>       |- error.html
>       |- signUp.html
>       |- displayingKeys.html 
>     |- Static
>       |- JS
>       |- IMGS
>       |- CSS
> ```

Comment: What's the actual HTTP response (status code, body, _etc._)?  Are there any relevant logs from either container?

Comment: well I found out that I actually have access to the backend container but I cant see the the HTTP response **keys_request.status_code** nor **ast.literal_eval(keys_request.content)** . They return nothing. Do you, please, have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same compose-file, docker-compose will create a default network from them, remove the network definitions and they should be accessible using `http://backend:5000` as url.

Baiscally when you call `docker-compose up`, you'll see that is says creating default network for all services within the compose file, which you can view using `docker network ls`.

To access services from the default-network, you use `http//:<service_name>:<port>`, where services for you are `backend` and `frontend`.

Network definitions are used when you want to bridge to containers that do not share a common network.

You can also use `http://localhost:5000` to access the backend node, once you remove the network definitions.

Comment: Hello :) I'd like to say that you are right about the default network created while executing [docker-compose up] **BUT** I still have the same issue I still can't access /generatekeys from my frontend container ...

Comment: I can access the /generateKeys() from the backend container but something is off with the HTTP response. I tried to print  **keys_request.status_code** : returns nothing and **ast.literal_eval(keys_request.content)** : returns raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node)) . Seems like the expression node or the string containing aren't any of the python literal structures (strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, bool, and None). Do you have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: I' d like to add that I don't have this issue when I run the applications on terminal. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey you need to send a dictionary as a response, with error as key and message as value

Comment: Hello :) the backend succeffelly send the response and the problem is situated in the frontend :backend     | 172.27.0.3 - - [02/Jul/2020 03:07:05] "POST /generateKeys HTTP/1.1" 300 -
frontend    | 172.27.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2020 03:07:05] "POST /SubmitCitizenInfo HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: there is something wrong with err = ast.literal_eval(keys_request.content) the whole **code** is on (https://github.com/OLakrari/mashakil) I'm really sorry to keep bothoring you but I'm really confused cause it works pefectly on my lap.

Comment: No worries, I'll take a look at it tonight and ping you right after I do.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks in advance :)